# Ajax POST call to code behind method, asking for windows authentication credentials

Tags: c#, ajax, authentication, windows-authentication

I am trying to call the function AddUser on my Accounts page:

```cs
    [WebMethod]
    protected bool AddUser(string userName)
    {
        ...
    }
```

with this ajax call, triggered by a button click:

```js
var nameParam = inputField.value;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Accounts.aspx/AddUser",
    data: {userName:nameParam}, 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (retValue) {
        console.log(retValue);
    }
});
```

Since my whole Web app is using windows authentication I get asked for my credentials, which I would like to avoid. However, when inputting the credentials for the account I am using, I get prompted again with no error message. It actually doesn't seem to matter what I input. I get prompted again and again, with no errors, no matter what.

Can I somehow avoid getting prompted at all? Since I am already authenticated, can't click the button if I'm not authenticated.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit 1:**

I just noticed that I get this javascript error:

```
Accounts.aspx/AddUser Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

**Edit 2:**

More detailed error:

```
jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 
POST http://localhost/DISMaintenanceSite/Accounts.aspx/AddUser 401 (Unauthorized)
send        @   jquery-3.1.1.js:9536
ajax        @   jquery-3.1.1.js:9143
submitUser  @   buttonScripts.js:120
onkeydown   @   Accounts:128
trigger     @   jquery-3.1.1.js:8177
(anonymous) @   jquery-3.1.1.js:8239
each        @   jquery-3.1.1.js:368
each        @   jquery-3.1.1.js:157
trigger     @   jquery-3.1.1.js:8238
addClick    @   buttonScripts.js:138
onclick     @   Accounts:130
```

I get this after finally hitting cancel on the prompt. During my attempts I still get no errors, whether they are correct or not.

Comment: In your code sample, data is a string and it's going to pass nameParam as a literal (not the value of a variable but the name). If that's okay then try '{"userName":"nameParam"}' which the kind of json .Net is expecting.

Comment: @derloopkat Fixed! But not related to the question at hand.

Comment: exactly the same error I'm receiving. How did u fix it? @Skillzore

Answer (score 0):

In your application, please go to `RouteConfig.cs` and change set the autodirectmode to `OFF` (which is `permanent` by default) like below:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var settings =new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
}
```